# How to add a custom grid to an ImageItem?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm working on some map projection interface code in pyqtgraph. My image is an aitoff-hammer projection, with the same general shape as the following atlas example:

aitoff-hammer map projection:
[image: aitoff-hammer map projection].

The problem is, my image doesn't have those grid lines. I've verified my code to convert pixel values to latitude/longitude coordinates works, but I'm having trouble coming up with an approach to make a custom grid. My current thought is to make a new image that just has grid lines, then make that a semi-opaque ImageItem. But, is it possible to stack ImageItems in pyqtgraph?

Comment: Yes, it is, but the problem I'd be more concerned about is the precision of the curves of those parallels. Depending on the type of projection and distortion used to create the map, you might have to ensure that the curves are correct: they could be probably simplified as cubic bezier curves, but I'm not completely sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

As [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) pointed out, I was able to stack ImageItems. I'll be evaluating the accuracy of the curves, but here is the relevant code:

```
def draw_grid(self, lon, lat, lon_int, lat_int):
    lon[np.isnan(lon)] = lon_int + 2
    lat[np.isnan(lat)] = lat_int + 2

    lon_cond = lon - (lon_int * (lon // lon_int)) <= 0.5
    lat_cond = lat - (lat_int * (lat // lat_int)) <= 0.5
    inds = np.where(lon_cond | lat_cond)
    
    grid = np.zeros(self.map_data.shape, dtype = np.uint8)
    grid[inds] = 255

    grid_image = pg.ImageItem(grid, axisOrder = 'row-major')
    grid_image.setZValue(10)
    grid_image.setOpacity(0.3)
    
    self.map_plot.addItem(grid_image)
```